# Summation over countable but infinite sets

Tags: isabelle-hol

I am trying to prove a simple property of sums over finite but countable sets (namely: all zero elements can be removed) in Isabelle/HOL. The `sum` function in the standard library (defined in Group_Big) is unsuited, because it assigns all infinite sets the unit element.

```
lemma infinite [simp]: "¬ finite A ⟹ F g A = ❙1"
```

(sum is later defined from F)

The property is easy to show when unfolding the definition of a sum over a finite set as the limit over the series of sums (where, for all n, the property holds). What library provides a good starting point? I've seen [Series.thy](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/Series.html) and and [Countable_Set](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Library/Countable_Set.html) but I am not sure how to combine them.

Comment: How do you define infinite sums in a group? Or exactly what sums are you considering?

Comment: Have you, by any chance, forgotten to mention that you are summing infinitely many elements, only finitely many of which are non-zero?

Comment: @Trebor: Some sum function that works (=where I can prove this property) with infinite countable sets and is preferably predefined in some library. Was this your question? I am not fixed on any particular one, but I need to admit I am only familiar with infinite series as the limit of the sums of series.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: It is possible that there are infinitely many non-zero elements. E.g., 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, and so forth.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about real numbers?

Comment: Yes (in the the application I have in mind; probabilities over discrete events)